# Only match folders in directory, ignore any files with extensions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to grab the latest version of a folder in a directory, but at the moment, I keep matching zip files in the same directory as well which are used for a different process. How do I ignore any files without an extension and only match folders? This is my code so far:

```
$versionToGet = (Get-ChildItem "$repo\StagingArea\$nameOfPackage" | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1).Name
```

How can I adjust this line to ignore any files with an extension and grab only folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-Directory` switch with [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1):

```
$versionToGet = (Get-ChildItem "$repo\StagingArea\$nameOfPackage" -Directory | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1).Name
```

---

The directory switch was introduced in PowerShell v3.0, for earlier versions, filter on the `PSIsContainer` noteproperty:

```
$versionToGet = (Get-ChildItem "$repo\StagingArea\$nameOfPackage" |Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |Sort CreationTime -Descending | Select -First 1).Name
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried filtering on the `PSIsContainer noteproperty` because I am using an older version of Powershell, but I am still picking up the *.zip file.

Comment: @methuselah Updated the answer, I erroneously added the `-not` operator in the Where-Object filter